# Is it possible to use Omnichannel feature through bot in your domain?

Tags: rocket.chat

I need scheme like with telegram bots, omnichannel but with RC bot. People will ask questions to bot, and some stuff will answers them in omnichannel chats. Something like inner ticket system. There is some ready-to-use solution?

Googled, but strange for me, not even a single similar question.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect botpress, diaglogflow,.. directly with your workspace, You could also make a connector yourself for any other bot if they support it.